# what is the use case for Yii exists function in models?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

Yii has a built-in "exists" function and i dont understand the scenario where i need to use this function.

the following query will result in NULL or the active record.

```
Posts::model()->findByPK('100')
```

This query will result in a boolean:

```
Posts::model()->exist(sql)
```

do i need to issues another query if the result is true? isnt that a "waste" of query? (i'm mainly concern about performance)

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the reason for the function itself is the **performance**..`findByPk` means load the model in a variable if found, `exixts` means check if found..Imagine a case where you just have to find out if there exists a record on given conditions, then why load the whole model instance in a variable and then check for its being null or not, instead have direct a boolean value..

If you need the model instance if it exists then if's ofc not useful, then as you said use directly `findByPk`..